# community/HelloWired_Free_Theme_1_4: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to connect20.magentocommerce.com:443

Tags: installation, themes, magento-1.9

I don't try to install some themes and other extensions on magento 1.9 on my mec.
The error is:

> community/HelloWired_Free_Theme_1_4: Unknown SSL protocol error in
>   connection to connect20.magentocommerce.com:443

Can you help me, please? 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento Plugin installation gives Error as : Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179181/magento-plugin-installation-gives-error-as-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-conne)

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use this code in downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

```
<?php
/**
* Magento
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
* needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
*
* @category    Mage
* @package     Mage_HTTP
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc.    (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
* @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*/

/**
* Class to work with HTTP protocol using curl library
*
* @category    Mage
* @package     Mage_Connect
* @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
*/
class Mage_HTTP_Client_Curl implements Mage_HTTP_IClient
{
/**
 * Session Cookie storage, magento_root/var directory used
 * @var string
 */
const COOKIE_FILE = 'var/cookie';

/**
 * Hostname
 * @var string
 */
protected $_host = 'localhost';

/**
 * Port
 * @var int
 */
protected $_port = 80;

/**
 * Stream resource
 * @var object
 */
protected $_sock = null;

/**
 * Request headers
 * @var array
 */
protected $_headers = array();


/**
 * Fields for POST method - hash
 * @var array
 */
protected $_postFields = array();

/**
 * Request cookies
 * @var array
 */
protected $_cookies = array();

/**
 * Response headers
 * @var array
 */
protected $_responseHeaders = array();

/**
 * Response body
 * @var string
 */
protected $_responseBody = '';

/**
 * Response status
 * @var int
 */
protected $_responseStatus = 0;


/**
 * Request timeout
 * @var intunknown_type
 */
protected $_timeout = 300;

/**
 * TODO
 * @var int
 */
protected $_redirectCount = 0;

/**
 * Curl
 * @var object
 */
protected $_ch;


/**
 * User ovverides options hash
 * Are applied before curl_exec
 *
 * @var array();
 */
protected $_curlUserOptions = array();

/**
 * User credentials
 *
 * @var array();
 */
protected $_auth = array();

/**
 * Set request timeout, msec
 *
 * @param int $value
 */
public function setTimeout($value)
{
    $this->_timeout = (int) $value;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{

}

/**
 * Destructor
 * Removes temporary environment
 */
public function __destruct()
{
    if (is_file(self::COOKIE_FILE)) {
        @unlink(self::COOKIE_FILE);
    }
}

/**
 * Set headers from hash

 * @param array $headers
 */
public function setHeaders($headers)
{
    $this->_headers = $headers;

}

/**
 * Add header
 *
 * @param $name name, ex. "Location"
 * @param $value value ex. "http://google.com"
 */
public function addHeader($name, $value)
{
    $this->_headers[$name] = $value;
}

/**
 * Remove specified header
 *
 * @param string $name
 */
public function removeHeader($name)
{
    unset($this->_headers[$name]);

}

/**
 * Authorization: Basic header
 * Login credentials support
 *
 * @param string $login username
 * @param string $pass password
 */
public function setCredentials($login, $pass)
{
    $this->_auth['login'] = $login;
    $this->_auth['password'] = $pass;
    //$val= base64_encode( "$login:$pass" );
    //$this->addHeader( "Authorization", "Basic $val" );
}

/**
 * Add cookie
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $value
 */
public function addCookie($name, $value)
{
    $this->_cookies[$name] = $value;
}

/**
 * Remove cookie
 *
 * @param string $name
 */
public function removeCookie($name)
{
    unset($this->_cookies[$name]);
}

/**
 * Set cookies array
 *
 * @param array $cookies
 */
public function setCookies($cookies)
{
    $this->_cookies = $cookies;
}

/**
 * Clear cookies
 */
public function removeCookies()
{
    $this->setCookies(array());
}


/**
 * Make GET request
 *
 * @param string $uri uri relative to host, ex. "/index.php"
 */
public function get($uri)
{
    $this->makeRequest("GET", $uri);
}

/**
 * Make POST request
 * @see lib/Mage/HTTP/Mage_HTTP_Client#post($uri, $params)
 */
public function post($uri, $params)
{
    $this->makeRequest("POST", $uri, $params);
}


/**
 * Get response headers
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getHeaders()
{
    return $this->_responseHeaders;
}


/**
 * Get response body
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBody()
{
    return $this->_responseBody;
}

/**
 * Get cookies response hash
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCookies()
{
    if(empty($this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'])) {
        return array();
    }
    $out = array();
    foreach( $this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'] as $row) {
        $values = explode("; ", $row);
        $c = count($values);
        if(!$c) {
            continue;
        }
        list($key, $val) = explode("=", $values[0]);
        if(is_null($val)) {
            continue;
        }
        $out[trim($key)] = trim($val);
    }
    return $out;
}


/**
 * Get cookies array with details
 * (domain, expire time etc)
 * @return array
 */
public function getCookiesFull()
{
    if(empty($this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'])) {
        return array();
    }
    $out = array();
    foreach( $this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'] as $row) {
        $values = explode("; ", $row);
        $c = count($values);
        if(!$c) {
            continue;
        }
        list($key, $val) = explode("=", $values[0]);
        if(is_null($val)) {
            continue;
        }
        $out[trim($key)] = array('value'=>trim($val));
        array_shift($values);
        $c--;
        if(!$c) {
            continue;
        }
        for($i = 0; $i<$c; $i++) {
            list($subkey, $val) = explode("=", $values[$i]);
            $out[trim($key)][trim($subkey)] = trim($val);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

/**
 * Get response status code
 * @see lib/Mage/HTTP/Mage_HTTP_Client#getStatus()
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->_responseStatus;
}

/**
 * Make request
 * @param string $method
 * @param string $uri
 * @param array $params
 * @return null
 */
protected function makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = array())
{
    static $isAuthorizationRequired = 0;
    $this->_ch = curl_init();

    // make request via secured layer
    if ($isAuthorizationRequired && strpos($uri, 'https://') !== 0) {
        $uri = str_replace('http://', '', $uri);
        $uri = 'https://' . $uri;
    }

    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    // force method to POST if secured
    if ($isAuthorizationRequired) {
        $method = 'POST';
    }

    if($method == 'POST') {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $postFields = is_array($params) ? $params : array();
        if ($isAuthorizationRequired) {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, self::COOKIE_FILE);
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, self::COOKIE_FILE);
            $postFields = array_merge($postFields, $this->_auth);
        }
        if (!empty($postFields)) {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
        }
    } elseif($method == "GET") {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    } else {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    }

    if(count($this->_headers)) {
        $heads = array();
        foreach($this->_headers as $k=>$v) {
            $heads[] = $k.': '.$v;
        }
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $heads);
    }

    if(count($this->_cookies)) {
        $cookies = array();
        foreach($this->_cookies as $k=>$v) {
            $cookies[] = "$k=$v";
        }
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode(";", $cookies));
    }

    if($this->_timeout) {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->_timeout);
    }

    if($this->_port != 80) {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_PORT, $this->_port);
    }

    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this,'parseHeaders'));

    if(count($this->_curlUserOptions)) {
        foreach($this->_curlUserOptions as $k=>$v) {
            $this->curlOption($k, $v);
        }
    }

    $this->_responseHeaders = array();
    $this->_responseBody = curl_exec($this->_ch);
    $err = curl_errno($this->_ch);
    if($err) {
        $this->doError(curl_error($this->_ch));
    }
    if(!$this->getStatus()) {
        return $this->doError("Invalid response headers returned from server.");
    }
    curl_close($this->_ch);
    if (403 == $this->getStatus()) {
        if (!$isAuthorizationRequired) {
            $isAuthorizationRequired++;
            $this->makeRequest($method, $uri, $params);
            $isAuthorizationRequired=0;
        } else {
            return $this->doError(sprintf('Access denied for %s@%s', $_SESSION['auth']['login'], $uri));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Throw error excpetion
 * @param $string
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function isAuthorizationRequired()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['auth']['username']) && isset($_SESSION['auth']['password']) && !empty($_SESSION['auth']['username'])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Throw error excpetion
 * @param $string
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function doError($string)
{
    throw new Exception($string);
}


/**
 * Parse headers - CURL callback functin
 *
 * @param resource $ch curl handle, not needed
 * @param string $data
 * @return int
 */
protected function parseHeaders($ch, $data)
{
    if(preg_match('/^HTTP\/[\d\.x]+ (\d+)/', $data, $m)) {
        if (isset($m[1])) {
            $this->_responseStatus = (int)$m[1];
        }
    } else {
        $name = $value = '';
        $out = explode(": ", trim($data), 2);
        if(count($out) == 2) {
            $name = $out[0];
            $value = $out[1];
        }

        if(strlen($name)) {
            if("Set-Cookie" == $name) {
                if(!isset($this->_responseHeaders[$name])) {
                    $this->_responseHeaders[$name] = array();
                }
                $this->_responseHeaders[$name][] = $value;
            } else {
                $this->_responseHeaders[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return strlen($data);
}

/**
 * Set curl option directly
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $value
 */
protected function curlOption($name, $value)
{
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, $name, $value);
}

/**
 * Set curl options array directly
 * @param array $array
 */
protected function curlOptions($array)
{
    curl_setopt_array($this->_ch, $arr);
}

/**
 * Set CURL options ovverides array  *
 */
public function setOptions($arr)
{
    $this->_curlUserOptions = $arr;
}

/**
 * Set curl option
 */
public function setOption($name, $value)
{
    $this->_curlUserOptions[$name] = $value;
}
}
```